# Regex for small decimal with 8 digits after decimal

Tags: javascript, regex, angular

I am having trouble with a decimal regex that needs to allow positive or negative numbers and up to 8 decimals.

Here is what I have.

```
^-?(?:(?:0|[1-9][0-9]*)(?:\.[0-9]{1,9})?|\.[0-9]{1,9})$
```

For the most part, this works, but it does not validate `.00000001` and I cannot figure out why.  It doesnt seem to work for any decimal where I have more than 6 zeros i a row.

```js
export class AmountValidateDirective implements Validator {

 validate(c: FormControl): any {
  
  let amount = c.value;
  const isValid = /^-?(?:(?:0|[1-9][0-9]*)(?:\.[0-9]{1,9})?|\.[0-9]{1,9})$/.test(amount);

   const message = {
     'amountValidate': {
       'message': 'Must be Decimal with less than 8 digits'
     }
   };
   return isValid ? null : message;
 }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you simple use [`^[+-]?\d*\.\d{1,8}$`](https://regex101.com/r/3h3dWQ/1)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
^[+-]?\d*\.\d{1,8}$
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3h3dWQ/2)**

**Explanation:**

- `^` - asserts the start of the line
- `[+-]?` - matches either `+` or `-`, optionally
- `\d*` - matches 0+ occurrences of a digit. This represent the digits before the decimal part.
- `\.` - matches the decimal point `.`
- `\d{1,8}` - matches a minimum of 1 digit and a maximum of 8 digits
- `$` - asserts the end of the line

Comment: nice+1! way easier than what he has currently ;-)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your current regex accept up to 9 decimals.
I have adapted it to have maximum 8 digits after the dot.

```
^-?(?:(?:0|[1-9][0-9]*)(?:.[0-9]{1,8})?|.[0-9]{1,8})$
                                   ^             ^
                                   ^             ^
```

I have tested it here and you can see the list of matches:
https://regex101.com/r/SQYgq9/1/

```
1
1234
1234.1234
123456.123456
1234567.1234657
12345678.12345678
12345678.1243546788 <NOT MATCHED
.91
0.12
.00001
.000001
.00000001
.000000001 <NOT MATCHED
.000000000 <NOT MATCHED
.0000000001 <NOT MATCHED
-1
-1234
-1234.1234
-123456.123456
-1234567.1234657
-12345678.12345678
-12345678.1243546788 <NOT MATCHED
-.91
-0.12
-.00001
-.000001
-.00000001
-.000000001 <NOT MATCHED
-.0000000001 <NOT MATCHED
```

If you still have issues for the input validation, you might have other problems like input not trimmed for example... From a regex point of view it is fine.

Comment: Sorry, I copied and pasted 9 digits as I was playing with this.  It looks like when I use a small number, if I do a console.log() on my value, it's turning into "1e-8".  I'm wondering if this is the value it's looking at when I do the regex test.  I'm not sure how to stop this from happening in Angular/Typescript